# Как правильно организовать получение серверных событий (Server Side Events) средствами PHP

Tags: php, server-side-events

Мне необходимо реализовать прием и чтение потоковых данных с сервера, который шлет Server Side Events в формате "Content-Type: text/event-stream" средствами php.

На JS все просто:

```
<script>
    if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
        var source = new EventSource("https://server.com");
        source.onmessage = function(event) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
        };
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
    }
</script>
```

А как такое PHP скриптом реализовать?????

Comment: PHP отвечает за отправку с сервера данных клиенту. Обработкой этих данных заниматься нужно на клиенте, то есть js.

Comment: Вы правы, но у меня клиент написан на PHP, по этому и возникла надобность в обработке этих данных средствами PHP

Comment: а в чем проблема добавить js-код? этому ничто не мешает. туториалов по обработке вагон и телега.

Comment: js и python код работает без проблем, но мне надо интегрировать этот функционал с существующим проектом на PHP

Comment: а какая разница куда js код вставлять. вы не поверите, но js и php тоже умеют взаимодействовать. и если погуглите свой вопрос, то найдете минимум десяток примеров по обработке в связке js+php.

Comment: Что значит какая разница? js выполняется в браузере, а мое приложение на PHP  работает в консоли и духом не ведает о существовании js, но оно должно слушать другой сервер и принимать от него данные также изящно как и приведенный мною js. писать костыли в виде AJAX-web морды или еще одного скрипта-демона на python я умею, но не хочу, вот и спрашиваю может кто ведает как реализовать клиент для Server Side Events средствами PHP

Comment: я не телепат и по вопросу никак не мог догадаться что у вас там происходит.  в части sse php умеет только отправлять данные. читать и слушать не может. по крайней мере на сегодняшний день таких библиотек нет.

Comment: Спасаибо, за ответ, жаль!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось все просто:

```
if ($stream = fopen('https://server.com/event-stream', 'r')) {// Открываем ресурс потока для чтения

    $send = false;//инициализируем флаг выхода

    while (!$send){//запускаем бесконечный глобальный цикл по условию
        $i = 0;// нумерация строк во внутренем цикле
        $stream_line_data = '';

        while (strlen($stream_line_data)<10){//запускаем бесконечный цикл чтения строк из потока (условие продолжения работы цикла может быть любым)
            $stream_line_data = stream_get_line($stream, 3072,"\n"); //читаем строку из потока максимальной длиной 3072 байта или до символа конца строки "\n", причем это может быть любое сочетание, например "id=15"
            $i++; //увеличиваем итератор номеров строк
            // Проверяем есть ли нужные нам данные в считаной строке
            if (strpos($stream_line_data,'ищем что нибудь в строке')===false){
                 $stream_line_data = '';// если нет данных опустошаем строку 
                 $out .= "no data"."\n"; //к переменной вывода дописываем  что нужных данных в этой строке нет
            }else{
                 $out .= $stream_line_data."\n";//к переменной вывода дописываем полученные данные
            }
        }
        echo $out; //организовываем обработку вывода прочитанных построчно данных
        $send = true;// организовываем условия выхода их глобального цикла
    }
    fclose($stream);//закрываем ресурс потока чтения
}
```

Если нужно читать данные непрерывно, то это все конечно лучше организовывать в виде демона, так как время жизни http соединения ограничено.